# how to Update/Edit database content with form in django

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i am trying to update content with form but in my html is does not load up whenn i click on the link any idea what causing the error

my views.py

```
def edit_address(request, id):
    address = Address.objects.filter(id=id)
    form = Addressform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.user = request.user
        form.save()
    else:
        form = Addressform()
    template_name = "address_edit.html"
    context = {
        "form": Addressform,
        "Address":Address.objects.get(id=id),
    }
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

i think the issue is in views.py that's why i only add this file tell me if you want to see any else file

my html

```
<div class="card col-10">
        <div class="form-group form-control-sm">
            <h1 class="text-center">Edit Address</h1>
            <a  class='back' style="float: right;" href="{% url 'accounts:home' %}">Back to site</a> <br>
            {% for Address in address %}
            <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.reciever_name|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.phone_no|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.alt_phone_no|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.state|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.city|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.pincode|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.address|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.locality|as_crispy_field }}</div>
             <div class="col-5">{{ form.eighteen|as_crispy_field }}</div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Add Address</button>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to obtain the *instance* of the address to edit, and pass it as `instance=…` to the `AddressForm`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def edit_address(request, id):
    address = get_object_or_404(Address, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addressform(request.POST, instance=address)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = AddressForm(instance=address)
    template_name = 'address_edit.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'Address': address,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: It might be better to use the [**`@login_required`** decorator
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)
> as a decorator, and thus wrap the function in it like:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
>
> @login_required
> def edit_address(request, id):
>     # …
> ```

---

> **Note**: You should *not* create a new form in case the form was not valid. A form
> that is not valid will store the problems with the input in the
> `form.errors` dictionary, and if you render the form (automatically),
> it will show the errors next to the fields where these errors occur.

Comment: in html nothing is showing except  heading

Comment: You need to render the form with `{{ form }}`.

Comment: added html file

Comment: @Shreyash: what happens if you use `{{ form }}` instead, just to eliminate the possibility that this has something to do with *rendering* the form.

Comment: The `{% for Address in address %}` does not seem to make much sense either. You can in fact eleminiate the loop (not the *body* of the loop, but the loop mechanism itself).